# GWT: TabLayoutPanel crashed app

Tags: java, gwt

I have a GWT app which uses the TabLayoutPanel using UiBinder. I have got UiBinder as:

```
<!DOCTYPE ui:UiBinder SYSTEM "http://dl.google.com/gwt/DTD/xhtml.ent">
<ui:UiBinder xmlns:ui="urn:ui:com.google.gwt.uibinder"
             xmlns:g="urn:import:com.google.gwt.user.client.ui">
    <g:TabLayoutPanel ui:field="tabLayoutPanel" barUnit="em" barHeight="3">
        <g:tab>
            <g:header>Welcome</g:header>
        </g:tab>
        <g:tab>
            <g:header>Login</g:header>
        </g:tab>
    </g:TabLayoutPanel>
</ui:UiBinder>
```

And the view code as:

```
public class MyView extends Composite {
    interface MyUiBinder extends UiBinder<Widget, MyView> {}
    private static MyUiBinder uiBinder = GWT.create(MyUiBinder.class);

    @UiField TabLayoutPanel tabLayoutPanel;

    public AuthenticateView() {
        initWidget(uiBinder.createAndBindUi(this));
    }
}
```

This code always crash with an error:

```
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Deferred binding failed for 'com.mycompany.MyView' (did you forget to inherit a required module?) at 
com.google.gwt.dev.shell.GWTBridgeImpl.create(GWTBridgeImpl.java:53) at
 com.google.gwt.core.shared.GWT.create(GWT.java:57) at 
com.google.gwt.core.client.GWT.create(GWT.java:85)
```

Could someone tell me what went wrong.

I did add this to a RootLayoutPanel through.

Many thanks

Comment: Deferred binding failed for 'com.mycompany.MyView' (did you forget to inherit a required module?) usually means you forgot to inherit  something in your gwt.xml

Comment: Can you share the rest of the stack trace?, and any other errors/warnings? It appears you are getting this in dev mode - can you share the error (if any) when you compile?

Answer (score 0):

As per [TablayoutPanel](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/TabLayoutPanel.html) docs

*This widget will only work in standards mode, which requires that the HTML page in which it is run have an explicit  declaration*

It seems problem with the DOCTYPE of your `host html page` .

can please  verify that your host HTML page has the doctype for standards mode only? 
Try with changing `<!DOCTYPE html>`.

And suggesting an [example](http://www.giantflyingsaucer.com/blog/?p=1062) to crosscheck and [TabPanel](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/1.5/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/TabPanel.html) also.

Answer (score 0):

You could get this error if the package containing the `MyView` class is not defined as a source package (using the `source` tag) in your `*.gwt.xml`.